# How to make rustdoc link to private item from submodule?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I am documenting my binary project that is split to multiple submodules. I have two files in `src/`:

```rust
// src/main.rs

//! # My Lovely Crate
//! 
//! I can reference [`sub::Public`].
//! But, can't reference [`sub::Private`].

mod sub;
```

and

```rust
// src/sub.rs

//! # My Lovely Sub

/// This struct is public.
pub struct Public {
    a: usize,
}

/// This struct is private.
struct Private {
    b: usize,
}
```

When I run this with

```
cargo doc --document-private-items
```

The resulting docs are generated for both structures in `sub`, but the reference to `sub::Private` doesn't resolve—the link is not generated.

Is there a workaround? Or, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: See https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/83049

Comment: @SolomonUcko thanks, I've seen that one. But still not sure how should I workaround the problem. Any ideas there?

Comment: It looks like it's just a warning, so what happens to the output? Is there the correct link, a broken link, or no link?

Comment: No, unfortunately I get no link. It gets rendered as text only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best workaround I have is to put a relative markdown link

```rs
//! But, can't reference [`sub::Private`](sub/struct.Private.html).
```

This should work in the simple case, but reexports or other complex cases might break it.